# rdiscount + haml in Rails 3 problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, haml, rdiscount

Ok, I hope this is a simple typo or something, but I've got a problem trying to get HAML to print markdown text. The relevant portion of my gemfile looks like this:

```
gem 'rdiscount'
```

My text looks like this:

```
### TEST HEADING ###
Here's some text.
```

My view code looks like this:

```
%h1= @article.title
.body
  :markdown
    = @article.body
```

but what renders on the page is:

> ## Article Title
>
> =  @article.body

So not only is it not formatting the markdown, it's not even outputting the content of `@article.body`.

Any help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use this instead:

```
%h1= @article.title
.body
  :markdown
    #{@article.body}
```